# How to set Linux network namespaces as a non-root user?

Tags: linux, networking

I set up a network namespace for a VPN so that not all the traffic goes over the VPN.
It works fine when I type:

```
sudo ip netns exec vpn firefox
```

All the Firefox traffic is now going through the VPN as expected. The problem is that every program that gets started like this has root permissions.
I tried to do:

```
sudo ip netns exec vpn sudo -u user firefox
```

While the application starts fine, it “leaves” the namespace and doesn't use the vpn anymore.

Can enyone help?

Comment: Are you sure it _leaves_ the namespace, as opposed to just contacting an existing instance (that's already outside) to open a new window?

Comment: After hours of searching around the answer is this simple haha. I really didnt think of that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Processes cannot 'leave' a namespace – the setns(2) function requires root privileges.

But most likely you already have an existing Firefox instance running outside the namespace. Whenever you run Firefox a second time, it just asks the existing instance to open a new window.

You can avoid this by using separate Firefox profiles, e.g. `firefox -profile /tmp/testfox`.